# How to expand Ceph OSD on LVM volume

Tags: ceph

I have three virtual servers with OSD daemons. Each OSD located on 300GB LVM partition. What should I do when VM disk will be increased to 500GB? Stop osd daemon service->increase lvm volume->start osd daemon service? Or will the procedure be more complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [ceph-bluestore-tool](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/man/8/ceph-bluestore-tool/)

```
ceph-bluestore-tool bluefs-bdev-expand –path <osd path>
```

while the OSD is offline to increase the block device underneath the OSD. Do this only for one OSD at a time.

Default `<osd path>` is `/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-12345/`